# RegEx: How can I match all characters until the next match?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a string like this:

```
Hello [@foo] how are you [@bar] more text
```

Ultimately I need to modify each instance of a substring matching `/\[@.+?\]/`, but I also need to modify each substring before/after the `[@foo]` and `[@bar]`.

The following regex matches the substring before a `[@.+]`, the `[@.+]` itself, then a substring after the `[@.+]` until the next character is followed by another `[@.+]`.

```
(.*?)(\[(@.+?)\])((.(?!(\[@.+?\])))*)
```

So the first match is "Hello [@foo] how are you" and the second match is " [@bar] more text".

Note the space at the beginning of the second match. That's the problem. Is there a way to get the first match to include all characters right up to the next `[@.+]`?

My regex includes characters after the `[@.+]` that are *not followed* by an instance of `[@.+]`, and I cannot see any way of getting it to include all characters until we are actually in another instance of `[@.+]`.

I'm really interested in whether I'm missing something - it certainly feels like there should be a simpler way to capture the characters around a given match, or a simpler way to capture characters not part of a match...

Comment: Change the position of dot in tempered dot match `(.*?)(\[(@.+?)\])(((?!(\[@.+?\])).)*)`

Answer (score 2):

You have this regex:

```
(.*?)(\[(@.+?)\])((.(?!(\[@.+?\])))*)
                   ^
```

Look at that dot. It precedes a negative lookahead. It matches a unit of data only if negative lookahead is satisfied. If negative lookahead fails, dot won't match. This happens at a character before matching a `\[@.+?\]`. Hence the space character isn't included.

To include it you just change the order. Put the dot after negative lookahead is passed:

```
(.*?)(\[(@.+?)\])(((?!(\[@.+?\])).)*)
                                 ^
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/VOCDil/1)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to separate your text into groups, each one having one instance of `[@.+]`, and all of the text must be matched into a group.

Try [`(?:^.*?)?\[@.+?\].*?(?=\[|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/NsyKnP/1).

Comment: NIce, thank you. I also need the different parts (before the `[@.+]`, the thing itself, and after it) grouped separately within each match. So I think this does what I need:
`(.*?)(\[@.+?\])(.*?(?=\[@.+?\]|$))`

Comment: You can use non-capturing groups `(?:)` instead of `()` but the result is the same. Do you need any more help or your problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/v7nHo3/1) might help you to get those vars.

```
(?:\[@[A-Za-z0-9]+\])
```

You can also add any other char to `[A-Za-z0-9]` such as <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd>:

```
`[A-Za-z0-9\.\+\@]`
```

and change it as you wish:

```
(?:\[@[A-Za-z0-9\.\+\@]+\])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'Hello [@foo] how are you [@bar] more text'
out = re.search('((.*)(\[.*\])(.*))((\[.*\])(.*))',x)
```

After getting above output you can use groups method to access different groups:

out.group(1)

'Hello [@foo] how are you '

---

out.group(2)

'Hello '

---

out.group(3)

'[@foo]'

---

out.group(4)

' how are you '

---

out.group(5)

'[@bar] more text'

---

out.group(6)

'[@bar]'

---

out.group(7)

' more text'